# I told him to wait until he is/was 30. - Which should I use? "Is" or "was"?

Tags: tense

**Example 1**

> I told him to wait until he is/was 30.

Let's assume he is only 27 right now.

Which should I use? **Is** or **was**?

Answer (score 1):

If he is not 30 yet, **either** would work.
If by the time the statement is made he is already 30, use "**was**".

So in your example, either "is" or "was" would be correct.